# Уничтожение и [вос]создание StringGrid

Tags: delphi, stringgrid

Имеются две формы. На второй форме - StringGrid, который в дизайне всяко-разно разукрашивается, настраивается и т.д. Задача - после манипуляций с StringGrid быстро его возвращать к первоначальному виду в рантайме. Желания программно запоминать его состояние для последующего восстановления никакого нет, т.к. это крайне трудозатратно, поэтому решил:
а) сохранять состояние StringGrid до изменений;
б) уничтожать StringGrid после изменений;
в) воссоздавать (восстанавливать) изначальный StringGrid.

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  TempSG: TStringGrid;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.SaveForm2SG1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TempSG := Form2.SG1;
end;

procedure TForm1.DestroyForm2SG1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Form2.SG1 <> nil then FreeandNil(Form2.SG1);
end;

procedure TForm1.RestoreForm2SG1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Form2.SG1 = nil then
  begin
    Form2.SG1 := TempSG;        // ерунда, т.к. объекта нет!
    Form2.SG1.Parent := Form2;  // AV
  end;
end;
```

В общем, хочу понять каким образом возможно сохранить состояние StringGrid, а потом динамически создать новый StringGrid с сохраненным ранее состоянием?

P.S. Изначально динамическое создание StringGrid с указанием всех свойств, повторюсь, не интересует. Вопрос о другом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.RestoreForm2SG1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
  tempForm2: TForm2;
begin
  tempForm2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
  try
    FreeAndNil(Form2.SG1);
    Form2.SG1 := tempForm2.SG1;
    Form2.SG1.Parent := Form2;
    tempForm2.RemoveComponent(tempForm2.SG1);
  finally
    tempForm2.Free;
  end;
end;
```

P.S. Не нужно перед вызовом `FreeAndNil` проверять на `nil`.

---

> Меня совсем обескураживает следующее ...

После строчки

```
    Form2.SG1 := tempForm2.SG1;
```

две ссылки указывают на один и тот же объект в памяти. Когда обнуляется/изменяется `tempForm2.SG1` (не уверен, что это происходит при вызове `RemoveComponent`), `Form2.SG1` продолжает указывать на этот объект.

Comment: Преогромнейшее спасибо! А можно узнать почему проверка на `nil` при уничтожении необязательна?

Comment: @UnityMan Эта проверка есть внутри `FreeAndNil`.

Comment: Я прошу простить мой малый ум, но Вы не могли бы уточнить через пожалуйста каким образом всё это функционирует? Меня совсем обескураживает следующее: `Form2.SG1 := tempForm2.SG1;` - вот тут элементу _Form2.SG1_ передается ссылка на элемент _tempForm2.SG1_; а вот тут `tempForm2.RemoveComponent(tempForm2.SG1);` происходит удаление элемента _tempForm2.SG1_, вследствие чего `tempForm2.SG1 := nil;`. Таким образом и `Form2.SG1 := nil;` (т.к. это ссылка), но по факту нулевым он не становится... Почему? Спасибо!

Comment: @UnityMan `но по факту нулевым он не становится`  - а как он узнает, что ссылка обнулилась? Если в телефоне записан Ункас Чингачгукович, а его вдруг убили, запись останется, пока об этом не сообщат, и Вы вручную не удалите запись.

Comment: @MBo, а зачем что-то узнавать, когда ссылка она на то и ссылка, что обратившись по ней можно нарваться на несуществующее?

Comment: @Igor, заглянул в _RemoveComponent_, но там по факту происходит удаление Owner'а: `AComponent.FOwner := nil;` - однако по итогу данной функции _tempForm2.SG1_ становится _nil_... Ничего не понимаю :(

Comment: @UnityMan Логика вопроса мне непонятна. Да, можно нарваться. Точно так, как с почтовым адресом - адресат может смениться или выбыть, или дом снесут. Для компонентов есть механизм нотификаций - уведомление об изменениях.